# Error when connecting a QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I am getting a compilation error for the following code. I cannot use signals with tree items:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int Grow();

public slots:
    void AddSubtree(QTreeWidgetItem *_jobItem, int _column);

private:
    void AddSubtree(QTreeWidgetItem *_jobItem, const QString &_filePath);
};

int MyClass::Grow()
{
    ...
    foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, filesList)
    {
        if(fileInfo.isDir())
        {
            const QString tag = fileInfo.fileName();

            QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
            item->setText(0, tag);

            // This works, but it is performance critical! Do it on demand
            //AddRunSubtree(item, fileInfo.filePath());

            // Load this tag's subtree on demand when clicked (error on this line)
            QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int col)),
                             this, SLOT(AddSubtree(QTreeWidgetItem*, int col)));

            parentItem->addChild(item);
        }
    }
}

void MyClass::AddSubtree(QTreeWidgetItem *_jobItem, int _column)
{
    //...
}

void MyClass::AddSubtree(QTreeWidgetItem *_jobItem, const QString &_filePath)
{
    //...
}
```

I am getting this compilation time error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MyClass::connect(QTreeWidgetItem*&, const char*, MyClass* const, const char*)'

Candidates are:

c:\Qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\kernel\qobject.h:204: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType)
c:\Qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\kernel\qobject.h:204: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QTreeWidgetItem*' to 'const QObject*'

c:\Qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\kernel\qobject.h:217: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, Qt::ConnectionType)
c:\Qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\kernel\qobject.h:217: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QTreeWidgetItem*' to 'const QObject*'

c:\Qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\kernel\qobject.h:337: bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const
c:\Qt\4.8.5\src\corelib\kernel\qobject.h:337: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QTreeWidgetItem*' to 'const QObject*'
```

Looking at the definition of QTreeWidgetItem, it effectively does not derive from QObject. Does it mean I cannot make the selection of a tree branch generate a signal?

If it is possible, what is wrong with my code?

Why does the error message contain 'MyClass::connect' instead of 'QObject::connect'?

Platform:
Qt 4.8.5
MinGW/g++
Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong class for the sender of the connection. You are using an item, whereas you should use the `QTableWidget` itself.

If you switch to that, and you set the connection once, your slot will be called.

Answer (score 2):

`QTreeWidgetItem` does not inherit from QObject, so it means it doesn not support signals/slots.

`void itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)` is signal from `QTreeWidget`, so you need to do it this way:

`QObject::connect(treeWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)),
                             this, SLOT(AddSubtree(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)));`

Also small note - you need to create this connection only once (in constructor) not on every item addition.

Comment: I did what you wrote, and the compile time error has gone. However, when running, the SLOT is never called. To be sure about that, I put an `exit(1)` in its implementation, with no effect.

Comment: And do you have any items in the tree widget? The `itemClicked` signal is emitted only when user clicks on the item.